# get place name by providing lat and long

Tags: java, android, geonames

In my application i want to get the weather report I'm using http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather="" for that by providing a city. But for me only lat and longitude is available

How can I get the place name by lat and longitudes.

Comment: just a tip: using a sentence with any combination of the words "send me teh codez plz" is a BAD idea and is unwanted on stackoverflow.

Comment: But do the extra words really invalidate the question? Can we not help him with his problem of parsing xml strings and suggest a low-effort path for his development?

Comment: @Kieveli Good point. I just removed all the noise and now the question reads a lot better. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, what you're doing is called reverse geocoding.

Most of the Geonames webservices are available in JSON, including findNearby.

Google also has a [reverse geocoding webservice](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#ReverseGeocoding)

What you're asking is not a small thing - a lat/lng database is almost certainly going to be presented in either XML or JSON, so it might be worth investing a little time and effort in this. Android must have xml/json wrappers?

Comment: It isn't too difficult to parse the XML - you don't do it yourself, you use a library.  Often you can get it working within 1-2 days of effort!

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to invoke the `Geocoder`, in this weather API, which BTW is not public so you should use it with caution, `city`, `state` and `country` are only informational fields, so you can use it like this (dummy constants):

```
private static final String URL = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=%s,%s,%s,%d,%d";
//...

final String url = String.format(URL, "city", "state", "country",
   p.getLatitudeE6(), p.getLongitudeE6());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Location API](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/location/package-summary.html) to get a [Address Object](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/location/Address.html) and get the locality from there

Comment: Great link. Love this answer. I just got an Android last week. Now I want to code for it =)

Answer (score 2):

Pass the latitude and longitude in your method and get the corresponding place name. Don't forget the user permissions:

```
public static String getUserLocation(String lat, String lon) {
   String userlocation = null;
   String readUserFeed = readUserLocationFeed(lat.trim() + "," + lon.trim());
   try {
      JSONObject Strjson = new JSONObject(readUserFeed);
      JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Strjson.getString("results"));
      userlocation = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1)
            .getString("formatted_address").toString();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   Log.i("User Location ", userlocation);
   return userlocation;
}

public static String readUserLocationFeed(String address) {
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
         "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + address
               + "&sensor=false");
   try {
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
      StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
      int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
      if (statusCode == 200) {
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         InputStream content = entity.getContent();
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
               content));
         String line;
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
         }
      } else {
         Log.e(ReverseGeocode.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
      }
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Android has a class called [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) for this stuff. Look at the `getFromLocation` method.