# how to get nearby city for weather forecast

Tags: android, weather

i am developing one application with map view i need display the weather depends on user place how can i get the weather report depending on the user lat and lon

Thanks

Aswan

Comment: This has nothing to do with Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [get place name by providing lat and long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363608/get-place-name-by-providing-lat-and-long/2364207#2364207)